# jquery datetimepicker disable today

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I want to allow selection of all weekends excluding today (if today is a weekend). However, the following code allows selection of today. This is what I am trying:

```
  jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    minDate:'+1970/01/01',
    maxDate:'+1970/01/10',
    defaultDate:'+1970/01/01',
    format:'d/m/Y',
    beforeShowDay: DisableWeekDays,
    closeOnDateSelect: true
 });

 function weekendsOnly(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day > 0 && day < 6), ''];
}

function DisableWeekDays(date) {
    var weekenddate = weekendsOnly(date);
    var disableweek = [!weekenddate[0]];
    return disableweek;
}
```

This is what I am using: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/
also, minDate doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - `minDate = tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);`

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

$("#minDate").datepicker({
    showOn: "none",
    minDate: tomorrow,
    dateFormat: "DD dd-mm-yy",
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        minDateChange;
    },
    inputOffsetX: 5,
});
```

Let me know if that works. I haven't tried it though. 
Your code might be something like:

```
 var today = new Date();
 var tomorrow = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
  jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    minDate:'+1970/01/01',
    maxDate:today,
    defaultDate:'+1970/01/01',
    format:'d/m/Y',
    beforeShowDay: DisableWeekDays,
    closeOnDateSelect: true
 });

 function weekendsOnly(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day > 0 && day < 6), ''];
}

function DisableWeekDays(date) {
    var weekenddate = weekendsOnly(date);
    var disableweek = [!weekenddate[0]];
    return disableweek;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, it works. all I had to do was set minDate to tomorrow. Oddly enough, I spent an hour trying to make "minDate:'+1970/01/02'," work, with many variations, it didn't work.

Comment: Good to hear! Glad I could help :) @Jayz

Comment: follow-up question. Is it possible to make coming Saturday as the default date? and it should always be the coming Saturday, whatever day of the week today might be.